# Trying to remake an array of JSON but it returns the same first element

Tags: javascript, json, promise

I'm trying to parse a list of JSONs and remake the JSON and add it to a different list. The problem is, one of the fields I need gets its value from a promise so I'm doing the processing inside that promise function.

for the list [a, b ,c], in my promise, I always have the first element for some reason. Any idea why?

```
self.checkedInterviews=[];
for (var i = 0; i < self.pendingInterviews.length; i++) {
  self.interviewModel = {
    interviewId: self.pendingInterviews[i].id,
    status: self.pendingInterviews[i].status,
    location: self.pendingInterviews[i].location,
    start: self.pendingInterviews[i].start,
    hideCheck: null
  };
  var promise = checkParticipant(self.pendingInterviews[i].id);
  promise.then(
    function(result) {
      self.interviewModel.hideCheck = result;
      self.checkedInterviews.push(JSON.stringify(self.interviewModel));
    },
    function(errResponse) {
      console.error('Error while check part');
    }
  );
}
```

My object literal:

```
this.interviewModel = {
  interviewId: null,
  status: null,
  location: null,
  start: null,
  hideCheck: null
};
```

Example of it being populated (JSON):

```
{"interviewId":10437,"status":"pending","location":"sdsa","start":-2179273464000,"hideCheck":false}
```

What self.checkedInterviews has in the end (JSON):

```
{"interviewId":10437,"status":"pending","location":"sdsa","start":-2179273464000,"hideCheck":false},{"interviewId":10437,"status":"pending","location":"sdsa","start":-2179273464000,"hideCheck":true},{"interviewId":10437,"status":"pending","location":"sdsa","start":-2179273464000,"hideCheck":false},{"interviewId":10437,"status":"pending","location":"sdsa","start":-2179273464000,"hideCheck":false},{"interviewId":10437,"status":"pending","location":"sdsa","start":-2179273464000,"hideCheck":true},{"interviewId":10437,"status":"pending","location":"sdsa","start":-2179273464000,"hideCheck":false}
```

The same thing 7 times...

I figured this is happening because javascript is Async and the promise function only gets the last thing. How do I fix it?

Comment: Where is the JSON?

Comment: it's loaded from the database

Comment: I can't see that, and you have asked and tagged the question [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). And what is `checkParticipant`?

Comment: You might want to consider showing some example JSON

Comment: because I'm making s json self.interviewModel... and trying to add it to self.checkedInterviews?

Comment: Edited and added examples

Comment: the second string is not json

Comment: The second is an array of JSONs

Comment: The latter is NOT the same thing seven times, it has different values of `hideCheck`.

Comment: That's because I get it through the promise, that'/s the only thing I get from the promise. Is there any way to pass what's outside the promise, inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by the time your promise `.then` functions run, the for loop is already finished, and `self.interViewmodel` already has the value of the last value of `i`.

So don't use `self.interviewModel` in them.

To make sure the promise doesn't "see" the new version of the variable, add another layer of function around it to invoke it, passing in the version it should use:

```
promise.then(
    (function(interviewModel) {
        return function(result) {
            interviewModel.hideCheck = result;
            self.checkedInterviews.push(JSON.stringify(interviewModel));
        }
    })(interviewModel),
    function(errResponse) {
      console.error('Error while check part');
    }
);
```

Comment: I dont understand. Isn't that what I'm doing? Creating an interviewModel from the pendingInterviews[i] ?

Comment: The problem is that the promise, when it runs, looks at the value of self.interviewModel _at that time_ -- after the loop has already finished.

Comment: @Mocktheduck: made a new version that has its own 'interviewModel' variable that won't look at the one that is being changed

Comment: it throws an error at the brackets and I cant figure them out. Like this, interviewModel will be empty cause initially it's filled with null and I need ti to have the values that self.checkedInterviews[i] has

Comment: You should still set self.interviewModel, then pass it to this function that creates your promise. I can't really test this myself, and I can't see an error at the brackets in my code

Comment: Ahh, I missed a }

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the object after the promise is finished

Do the following

```
self.checkedInterviews=[];
for (var i = 0; i < self.pendingInterviews.length; i++) {
  var promise = checkParticipant(self.pendingInterviews[i].id);
  promise.then(
    function(result) {
     var interviewModel = {
        interviewId: self.pendingInterviews[i].id,
        status: self.pendingInterviews[i].status,
        location: self.pendingInterviews[i].location,
        start: self.pendingInterviews[i].start,
        hideCheck: result
      };
      self.checkedInterviews.push(JSON.stringify(interviewModel));
    },
    function(errResponse) {
      console.error('Error while check part');
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I do like this self.checkedInterviews=[];